# Fisher's Exact Test: Compare 'A' vs 'Not-A'

Tags: r, categorical-data, fishers-exact-test

I have data, which, as a table, is akin to this:

```
        C1  C2  C3
____________________
A   |   10  97  168
B   |   1   22  33
C   |   19  102 201
D   |   1   35  58
SUM |   31  256 460
```

If I want to determine if there is any relationship between the columns and, e.g., row 'A', would it be ok to perform a fisher test of row 'A' against the sum of all Non-A rows?

ie:

```
notA  <- aTable['SUM',] - aTable['A',]
evalA <- rbind(aTable['A',], notA)
fisher.test(evalA)
```

Comment: If the question naturally suggests dichotomizing the categories then, “yes”, you can compute that p-value. However, it would seem that you are losing data and insight to bin, as is usually the case.

Comment: Yes, as Todd said, you may do dichotomizing/binning into fewer categories if that lost in information is all right for you (i.e. if you want to pretend the merged categories "don't exist" for your task at hand.

Comment: Solved as per comments of [Todd D](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360245/fishers-exact-test-compare-a-vs-not-a?noredirect=1#comment676941_360245) and [ttnphns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360245/fishers-exact-test-compare-a-vs-not-a?noredirect=1#comment676947_360245)